# In case expression with summation, round currency to closest dollar

Tags: sql-server

I would like to round the currencies in the below output to the nearest dollar, such that $28,143.97 becomes $28,144, for example. It would seem the `round([some variable], 2)` function would work best as explained in similar posts. However, when applied in my CASE expression, the following error occurs:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

The closest I can get to my desired output uses this query:

```
select 
[Financial Class]
,format(sum(case when [Month] = 'May' then [Credits] else 0 end),'c','en-US') [May]
,format(sum(case when [Month] = 'June' then [Credits] else 0 end),'c','en-US') [June]
,format(sum(case when [Month] = 'July' then [Credits] else 0 end),'c','en-US') [July]
from (
SELECT 
fc.financial_class_name [Financial Class]
,case
        when AGING_DATE >= '2020-07-01' AND AGING_DATE < '2020-08-01' then 'July'
        when AGING_DATE >= '2020-06-01' AND AGING_DATE < '2020-07-01' then 'June'
        when AGING_DATE >= '2020-05-01' AND AGING_DATE < '2020-06-01' then 'May'
        else null end [Month]
,sum(HAR_AMOUNT)  as [Credits]
FROM HSP_BKT_AGING_HX hx
left join clarity_fc fc on hx.har_fin_class_c=fc.financial_class
WHERE 
HAR_ACCT_STATUS_C IN ('4')
AND HAR_AMOUNT < 0
AND AGING_DATE >= '2020-05-01' AND AGING_DATE < '2020-08-01'
group by aging_date, financial_class_name
) x
group by [Financial Class]
```

Which produces this output:

[image]

Comment: You should show what you tried, it takes time to experiment/guess how you might have applied `ROUND()` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'c0'` instead of `'c'` in the `format()` function which will also round to the nearest integer :

```
............................
,format(sum(case when [Month] = 'May' then [Credits] else 0 end),'c0','en-US') [May]
,format(sum(case when [Month] = 'June' then [Credits] else 0 end),'c0','en-US') [June]
,format(sum(case when [Month] = 'July' then [Credits] else 0 end),'c0','en-US') [July]
............................
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but this still leaves the hundredths-place decimal ".00"... How would I remove those? Again, looking for $28,143.97 to become $28,144, not $28,144.00.

Comment: ...or just stop using FORMAT() here ([FORMAT() is expensive](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)) and make it look money-pretty at the presentation layer.

Comment: @GabeVerzino I hope you saw my last edit, because there is no need of round() if you use `'c0'`.

Comment: @forpas I see it, yep. Beautiful. Thanks so much.